# How to pick host name in Per service logs in WSO2 ESB

Tags: logging, log4j, wso2, pattern-layout, wso2-esb

I am making Per service Logs in WSO2 ESB according to their [official](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Per-Service+Logs+in+WSO2+ESB) link. The layout conversion pattern is working fine but it is not picking up the **"HostName"**. I don't know whats the problem , WSO2 using this pattern itself in "log4j.properties" file. But it is not working in per service logs.

**Note:** I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

**Configurations in "log4j.properties" file:**

```
# Seperate LOG File for MyService Service
log4j.category.SERVICE_LOGGER.MyService=INFO, MyService_PROXY_APPENDER
log4j.additivity.SERVICE_LOGGER.MyService=false
log4j.appender.MyService_PROXY_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MyService_PROXY_APPENDER.File=logs/MyService-service.log
log4j.appender.MyService_PROXY_APPENDER.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
log4j.appender.MyService_PROXY_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MyService_PROXY_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}] - %5p - [%X{host}] - %c{1} - %n
```

This is creating the separate log file and logging the following output.

**Output:**

```
[2015-01-14 12:37:34,063] -  INFO - [] - MyService -
```

**Problem:**

The rest of Conversion specifiers are working fine but `[%X{host}]` is not working.

Comment: @user3141034 can you please look into the matter??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that **host** and **ip** MDC entries used by default in log4j conversion patterns (for ERROR_LOGFILE, SERVICE_APPENDER, ... appenders) are not initilized in 4.8.1

A workaround could be to initialize host's value by yourself, with this script at the start of your mediation for example :

```
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[
        importPackage(Packages.java.net);
        importPackage(Packages.org.apache.log4j);
        try {
            var addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            if (addr != null) {
                var hostname = addr.getHostName();
                MDC.put("host", hostname);
            }
        } catch (e) {
        }
    ]]></script>
```

But this is just a workaound and I'm interested in a better solution

Comment: Thanks it worked, but i don't understand that why these entries are not initialized in 4.8.1.

Comment: Can you please also guide me that how to get pid in WSO2 using script mediator?

Comment: var ip = addr.getHostAddress();

Comment: brother i am talking about process id not ip. I want PID not ip.. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: ip / pid ... sorry, I must learn to read ;-)   Seriously, I can't help you with PID